# "check_http_json.py" NAGIOS Plugin is not working

Tags: python, json, plugins, nagios

I installed `check_http_json.py` (URL: https://github.com/drewkerrigan/nagios-http-json) on my Nagios server to parse the JSON output & setup rules based on specific keys.

JSON output looks like below:

```
[{"key":"Key","value":"Value"},{"key":"Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Disallowed], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]","value":"8"},{"key":"Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Pending], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]","value":"2"},{"key":"Last Execution for Notification Service ended","value":"10/21/2015 22:23:44PM"},{"key":"Last Execution for Payment Processor ended","value":"10/21/2015 22:23:45PM"},{"key":"Last Execution for Intelligent Offers ended","value":"10/21/2015 21:55:19PM"}]
```

On Nagios side, when I run the below command which checks the availability of json output; it works and return a result:

command:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http_json.py -H datamgrqa.example.local -p api/NOC/ValidateBackend
```

output:

```
OK: Status OK
```

But when I run the below command which checks if the following key "Last Execution for Notification Service ended" is exist or not,

```
usr/bin/python /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http_json.py -H datamgrqa.example.local -p api/NOC/ValidateBackend -e "Last Execution for Notification Service ended"
```

I get the below result, despite that the key is persist as you see in the JSON output above:

```
WARNING: Status check failed, reason: Key Last Execution for Notification Service ended did not exist
```

And when I run the below command which verify if the key "Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Pending], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]"  has a value less than or equal to 50:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http_json.py -H datamgrqa.example.local:80 -p api/NOC/ValidateBackend  -l "Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Pending], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]",50
```

I get the below error:

```
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http_json.py", line 263, in <module>
is_alive, reason = processor.isAlive()
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http_json.py", line 136, in isAlive
k, v = kv.split(',')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any Idea Please?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation due to the implementation of `check_http_json.py`.

The value you pass into `-l` has 2 commas in it.

```
"Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Pending], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]",50
```

On line 137 of [`check_http_json.py`](https://github.com/drewkerrigan/nagios-http-json/blob/master/check_http_json.py#L137)

It's splitting that whole string on the comma (`,`) and it's expecting to get back only 2 tokens: key (`k`), and value (`v`).

```
if self.rules.key_lte_list != None:
    for kv in self.rules.key_lte_list:
        k, v = kv.split(',')
        if (self.helper.lte(k, v) == False):
            reason += " Value %s was not less than or equal to value for key %s." % (v, k)
```

However, because your "key" has a comma in it, splitting the whole string (including the `,50` value part) on comma will return 3 tokens:

- token1: `"Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Pending]`
- token2:  `OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]"`
- token3: `50`

That's why you're getting the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.
It's expecting 2 tokens after the split, but it's getting 3.

Bottom line is, if you want to use this `check_http_json.py` plugin as-is, your keys can't have any commas in them.

**EDIT: (work-around)**

If you need a work-around, you can modify `check_http_json.py`
Replace every instance of `k, v = kv.split(',')` with something using a different separator character that doesn't appear in your keys. For example:
`k, v = kv.split('@')`

Then modify the way you pass in arguments to the script. Instead of using a comma to separate your key and value, use something like an `@` instead.

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http_json.py -H datamgrqa.example.local:80 -p api/NOC/ValidateBackend  -l "Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Pending], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]@50"
```

**Note:**  I moved the ending double-quote `"` to enclose the `@50` because I think you'll get unintended results without it.  Try it both ways to be sure.

Comment: I have updated the python file and ran your command, but I get below Warning:
WARNING: Status check failed, reason: Value 3 was not less than or equal to value for key Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Disallowed], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]. while the value of the key " Receipt count in last 24 hours with status [Disallowed], OCR status [Complete] and Matching status [N/A]" was 11 when I ran the command ( does not return the correct answer).

Comment: Actually I suspect that the key should be one single word without spaces like: 
"Receiptcountinlast24hourswithstatus[Disallowed],OCRstatus[CompleteandMatchingstatus[N/A]" 

this plugin unable to read a specific Key and confirm it's availability as I mentioned earlier in my question description.

Comment: You can try: k, v = split('",')  To split on the double-quote and comma combination.  But there may (will) be cases when that double-quote may not be there, so you'll have to check that and account for it.